# Sufficient Conditions for a family of $L^p$ bounded measurable functions to satisfy $\left\Vert \sup_{X\in\mathscr{C}} |X|\right\Vert_p<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, measurable-functions

Suppose $\mathscr{C}$ is a family of random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ be $\mathcal{L}^p$-bounded. i.e. 
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{X\in\mathscr{C}} \left\Vert X\right\Vert_p <\infty
\end{equation*}

Then is it necessarily true that 
\begin{equation*}
\left\Vert \sup_{X\in\mathscr{C}}\left\vert X\right\vert\right\Vert_p<\infty
\end{equation*}
If so - could someone please show me a proof? And if not, what would be the weakest sufficient conditions which would make this statement true (and how would you prove it).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the words "random variables" so I am assuming that $\mu$ is a probability measure, i.e., $\mu(\Omega)=1$.

In this case, your claim is **false** unless $p=\infty$. When $p=\infty$ it is easily verified to be true.

Let $p<\infty$. We let $\Omega=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

For $n \in \Bbb N$ and $0 \leq k \leq n-1$ we define $X_{n,k}$ to be $n^{1/p}$ times the indicator function of the interval $[k/n, (k+1)/n]$. Then clearly $\|X_{n,k}\|_p=1$ for all $k$ and $n$. However $\sup_{n,k}|X_{n,k}| = +\infty$ since $n^{1/p} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence $$\big\| \sup_{n,k} |X_{n,k}| \big\|_q = +\infty,\;\;\;\;\;\; \forall q \in [1,\infty]$$

The weakest conditions (of which I know) that would make your claim true is that $p>1$, $\mathscr C = [0,\infty)$ or $\mathscr C = \Bbb N$, and $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a **submartingale**. In this case, the result follows from **Doob's $L^p$ inequality**: $$\big\|\sup_{t \geq 0}|X_t| \big\|_p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \sup_{t \geq 0} \|X_t\|_p$$

Comment: Hi Shalop, Thanks so much for this really insightful answer!!! =) Is there any chance you would know of a good reference/link/resource which would show how to prove Doob's Lp inequality in continuous time for $\mathscr{C} = [0,\infty)$??

Comment: @User086688 Sure, see proposition 2.39 on page 59 of [this book by Mörters and Peres](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~peres/bmbook.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this!